# Java Enum with multiple datatype fields?

Tags: java, enums

I have following fields

```
a(String)
b(String)
c(String)
d(boolean)
e(boolean)
```

Is it possible to have them all in an Enum like following?

```
public enum Fields {
  a("A")
  b("B")
  c("C")
  d(true)
  e(false)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have them but you should define constructors which takes  `String` or `boolean` as parameters.

```
public enum Constants {

CONSTANT_STRING1("CONSTANT_VALUE1"), 
CONSTANT_STRING2("CONSTANT_VALUE2"), 
CONSTANT_STRING3("CONSTANT_VALUE3");
CONSTANT_FLAG1(false);
CONSTANT_FLAG2(true);

private String constants;
private boolean flag;

private Constants(String cons) {
this.constants = cons;
}

private Constants(boolean lFlag) {
this.flag= lFlag;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using an enum to store constants, which is bad practice.

Comment: is it, as far as I read(correct me if I am wrong) the fields are public static final, which means we are creating constants

Comment: enums are for enumerated values (months, planets, etc.). If your values are constants which have nothing in common, you shouldn't store them as enums, but as regular constants.

Comment: yes, some people decide they want to take their "public static final String HTML_ELEM_IMG = "<img>"" type variables and redo them in enums, that's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but I would advice against it. In most cases, what you really want is a common interface, which is implemented by two (or more) different classes.

Please also note that is fully legitimate for an enum to implement an interface, but it is seldom you see two enums implement the same interface like in the example below:

```
public interface Fields {
}


public enum StringFields implements Fields {

    A("A"),
    B("B"),
    C("C")

    private StringFields(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }

    private final String str;
}


public enum BooleanFields implements Fields {

    D(true),
    E(false);

    private BooleanFields(boolean val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    private final boolean val;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can have two different constructors in the enum, but that means you need to have two fields (with one of them not being set). I do not think this would make much sense.

```
public enum Fields {
    a("A"), b("B"), c("C"), d(true), e(false);

    Fields(String str) {

        strval = str;
        value = false;

    }

    Fields(boolean val) {

        strval = null;
        value = val;

    }

    private final String strval;
    private final boolean value;

}
```

EDITED*** Compiles now. You have to initialize both at the same time.

Comment: @RockyTriton, exactly. This will not make sense.

Comment: The code does not compile. You must initialize a `final` member variable.

Comment: @matsev Not going to lie, I did not test it and you are right. This is an edge case though, something most people will not encounter. I fixed it.